# how to create new controller under folder in magento

Tags: php, magento

I have a situation like I need to create a controller inside a folder, so the structure will be,

```
module_name/mobile/productcontroller.php
```

and I have added following code in that file,

```
class Mypackage_Mymodule_Mobile_ProductController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {

public function indexAction() {
echo 'got it';
exit;
}
```

And Im trying to access using below url

http://localhost:8888/magento/index.php/Mymodule/mobile/productcontroller?&start=1

IM getting 404 error. So is there any wrong in my class ? Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create a subfolder into controllers folder, create it using the camelcase like `Mobile`. so the folder structure will be:

`Mypackage/Mymodule/controllers/Mobile/ProductController.php`

and the url to access the controller will be:

`http://localhost:8888/magento/mymodule/mobile_product/`

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this:
http://localhost:8888/magento/index.php/Mymodule/mobile/product

remove controller from the end.. you don't have to mention controller name.
change `mobile/productcontroller`  to `mobile/product`

```
baseurl/frontName/controllername/action
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the URL of your custom controller using this command:

```
$this->getUrl('nameOfFolderContainingYourController_YourControllerName/actionNameToCall');
```